# Variant Type cutting off at 2 decimal places instead of 4

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a custom function in Excel VBA to get the last number of a specific criteria.

The function is as follows:

```
Public Function GetLastIf(ByRef LookupRange As Range, ByVal MatchVal As Variant, ByVal RangeOffset As Integer) As Variant

Dim FRow As Long
Dim lastVal As Variant
For FRow = 1 To LookupRange.Rows.Count
    If LookupRange(FRow, 1) = MatchVal Then
        lastVal = Round(LookupRange(FRow, 1 + RangeOffset).Value, 4)
    End If
Next

GetLastIf = lastVal

End Function
```

The range I'm looking in has two "Jul" values in the first column. The next column are 4.2641 and 4.2602, respectively, so the desired output should be 4.2602. This function (GetLastIf(range, "Jul", 1)) is only spitting out 4.2600. I'm wondering if I'm misusing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim lastVal As Double
```

Variant can sometimes gives unexpected results.

And you may want to format instead of round.

```
Debug.Print Format(lastVal ,"0.0000")
```

That will set your value to 4 decimal places.

Comment: Yeah I had done that, it's still giving me 4.2600 instead of 4.2602. What's strange is that when I call the function out of the VBA console, it provides the correct number.

Comment: Also I had intended to keep it as a variant, as I'm not sure if there will be Text in the given cell.... although.... I guess I could probably just throw in some error handling to catch it

Comment: Did you try Format instead of Round?

Comment: That's what I was referring to in my first comment. Yes